# I lost windows 7 after installing grub-customizer

Tags: dual-boot

I did this thing and win 7 is gone. Please help me to get me that back. It is important as lots of my work files are not opening.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Comment: You should be able to access the files from ubuntu by mounting the windows partition.

Comment: I think you are right. Can you help me how to do it as I am unable to do it. I hibernated my win 7 and now it is not mounting.

Comment: Use `blkid` to determine the /dev/sda number of the windows partition, then run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdax` but replace sdax with the actual number of the windows partition, such as sda5 or sda1, whatever it may be. You should be able to mount the partition after running that command.

Comment: I typed         sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5.  But message comes "command not found. Thank you for your quick help. I also tried to mount the drive but message coming "only root caan do that"

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way [Dual boot: how to target the new grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704794/dual-boot-how-to-target-the-new-grub) but you may need to **Reinstall GRUB** instead of **Restore MBR**.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. But I am very new, please help me with reinstalling also.

Comment: I checked and found this message for my C drive:  Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/gaurav/9C1CF5951CF56AA2: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/gaurav/9C1CF5951CF56AA2"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option

Comment: Follow the guide I've given in answer. It's quite clear.