# How to recover Ubuntu GRUB after installing another Linux distribution?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I use Ubuntu GRUB.

After installing some other Linux distribution Ubuntu GRUB disappears and the other distribution's GRUB appears.

How can I recover the Ubuntu GRUB?

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and reinstall its grub from inside Ubuntu. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` And you may be able to turn off the other install from reinstalling its copy of grub. But these instructions are for Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update

Comment: @oldfred: Could you please post answers as such and not as comments? Comments don't go through the same review and voting processes that keep the quality of the content of SE high. Thanks.

Comment: The possible answer is in the link. Do we want same answer in multiple posts?

Comment: @oldfred See above: Just flag it as a duplicate: You have enough rep to do that!  :-)