# Reinstall GRUB overwriting existing GRUB installation

Tags: grub2

I have Ubuntu 17.04 in one partition, and Elementary loki in another partition.

I updated Loki and it updated the GRUB bootloader, now Elementary is the first option.

I want to update my Ubuntu install to use Ubuntu's GRUB configuration

Already tried with `update-grub` and `update-grub2` with no success

I can boot properly into both partitions, I just want to restore Ubuntu's grub conf.

Comment: Install grub from ubuntu then update grub from ubuntu. that should make ubutuntu default boot again.

Comment: Grub also remembers where to reinstall on major updates. Not sure if Elementary is the same as Ubuntu, but you may want to see if this works to stop Elementary from reinstalling grub on a major update. https://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update/503446#503446